# Column as alias is ambigous in Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am migrating the database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. In MySQL I create a view like this:

```
create or replace view translated_attributes_with_attribute_templatevalues as
    select
        concat_ws('',
            translated_attributevalues.attribute_id,
            translated_attributevalues.languagecode,
            attribute_template_value.id
        ) AS id,
        ...
        GROUP BY id
```

But in PostgreSQL I got the message:

> column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...GROUP BY id

How can I use the alias "id"?

I renamed it, but than other parts of the code break, because it assumes the column is named id.

Answer (score 2):

Either repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY concat_ws('', ...)
```

or use the result column number:

```
GROUP BY 1
```

The only advantage of the first solution is that it complies with the SQL standard.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer as "correct" then.